# JQuery / Ajax Form Validation - How to not submit form unless form validates and ajax validates

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

I am using this form validator (http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) and am having issues getting it to properly validate both the regular fields and 2 fields I have using AJAX validation.

The 2 ajax fields are used to determine if a username and directory are already in use as we can't have duplicates in the database.

I want to validate the form, then have it execute an ajax request to submit the information to the database.
I can use $('#myform').validationEngine('validate') to return true or false if the form (without AJAX validation) validates. But I am unsure how to return a true or false for both regular and ajax validation at once as that method only works for non-ajax validation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just check if the fields are empty, and have correct data before sending the ajax request?

Comment: I dont quite follow. For the normal fields, I have it validate that they are not empty. But the 2 fields (directory and username) have to have information entered, then checked via ajax to see if they are already being used, then returned as valid or invalid. That portion works. However, using the 'validate' option for the validator doesnt actually validate that the ajax fields are valid or not. So it still submits even if those aren't valid entries but all the regular fields are. Thats the issue.

Comment: Are they different <form> 's?  They should be, right?  Your going to run into problems customizing this because the form validation packages usually works on one form.  I think at this point your going to have dig into the callback functions of the validator itself, and start to understand how you can modify it to your needs.

Comment: Another issue is what do you mean by validation?  Walk me through the logic here,  the first two fields are sent across and come back with "valid" or "not valid" .  It then populates the ajax fields with the "valid" name, because they are read-only right?  Then when you submit again you will still have to check your values (because your storing info in the page) but at that point if the username and directory are filled then that counts as valid, right?  Because do you mean it should be invalid if its in the database?  There are a lot of ideas here that are unclear, so you should post code.

Comment: I have stated in other post that, sometimes, solutions for simple problems come in the form of 20K .... 100k plugins. Are you sure that you need that ....mess? You are, for what I could understand, just using two fields to validate an entire form. Just use pure javascript and jquery to validate the two original fields returning a json and furnishing that information to the next step: $.post('url','userName='+username+'&directory='+directory,function (data) { eval('var json='+data); if this ... });

Comment: Jakx: It is one form. The code is too much to put up here, but basically the form contains contact information (name, address, etc.) some of which are required. Then there is login information (username, password, directory). The username and directory have to be unique (i.e. the ajax check for whats in the database already). The ajax returns either valid or invalid for whatever the user inputs. If valid, a green message is displayed by the plugin, invalid a red message. The issue is that the form will still submit if all required fields are entered and the ajax fields are invalid.

Comment: The reason I want to use the plugin is purely for the clean/simple UI that is used to return any missing/incorrect data entered in the fields.

Comment: Can't you just set that field to read-only after it has been approved?  Then just make it required.  That would probably require two forms though.  The first form to get the green light and fill in the read only value.

Comment: I ended up just dropping the plugin and creating my own validation process. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Good I'm glad you got it working.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.